# how do i connect to redis server in python script inside a Docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, redis, dockerfile

Here is my python file 'app.py'

```
import redis
cache = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379)
for i in range(8):
  cache.set(i,i)
for i in range(8):
  print(cache.get(i))
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
COPY . /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

But when i built and run docker image i am getting error not able to connect.

Comment: What's the error?  What should the host name `redis` match?

Answer (score 0):

The container you run based on the image does not know who 'redis' is. You can tell it by using the `--add-host` option to `docker run`.

Find out the public IP of your redis server. Then use that IP to map it to the `redis` hostname that your script tries to connect to.

```
docker run --add-host redis:<public_ip> ....
```

Comment: It'd be better still to use the server's DNS name; `--add-host` is manual configuration you'd have to reproduce every time you run the container.